# UIButton toggle title. Only changes after 2nd click

Tags: ios, uibutton, viewcontroller

I've looked at lots of examples here of how to do a toggle button. My toggle button detects the initial state ok, so when the view loads it says "remove" or "add to favorites" correctly but then when I click on it, nothing changes.

2nd time around it changes the text like it should... after that it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (IBAction)addToFav:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Sending Favorite Button Click message to delegate");
NSLog(@"Delegate is: %@", self.delegate);

[self.delegate clickedOnFavoriteButton:self];

if (favo==YES) {
    self.favorite = @"notFavorite";
    [favoriteButton setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    favo = NO;

}
else if (favo == NO){
    self.favorite = @"favorite";
    [favoriteButton setTitle:@"Add to Favorites" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    favo=YES;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `favo` ivar is initialized correctly.

Comment: Hi Sergio, favo is initialized in viewDidLoad and seeing that the rest of the code inside the if gets executed I'm fairly certain that's not the problem.

Comment: Could you provide viewDidLoad and explain how you create the button (IB vs. code)? I also wonder about the `clickedOnFavoriteButton:` function...

Comment: Hi Sergio, I'm a real idiot! Realised what the error was, I was setting the title back the front.